# Upnp: list portmappings

Tags: python, upnp

I'm currently looking at the miranda upnp tool (http://code.google.com/p/mirandaupnptool/). Is there a way for upnp to list all portmappings. I was able to forward ports an delete portmappings but I couldn't find a way to list all mappings.

I've read somewhere that [this mac os x tool](http://www.mackozer.pl/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/portmap.png) does list all portmappings on your router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some devices support the [GetGenericPortMappingEntry](http://code.google.com/p/tcmportmapper/source/browse/TCMPortMapper/framework/miniupnpc/testupnpigd.py?r=abdaefc8f75b4076e464a52f52273a3dd36ed888) method.

Comment: Ah, yes. Together with PortMappingNumberOfEntries that should work. Thanks!